# CRUD interface on JSF page is not updating to reflect the adding of new entities

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces

This is my first time using JSF, Hibernate, and Primefaces all at once. My CRUD has a submit button on a new category dialog. The button is coded like so:

```
 <p:commandButton value="Submit" update=":form:categoryTable"
                                 actionListener="#{categoryController.addCategory}"/>
```

Now, it should be updating the categoryTable with new elements added to the model. But it is not? What could the problem most likely be?

Also, once a new category has been added, hitting the submit dialog doesn't make it disappear.  I can see the category appearing in the model but I want the dialog to disappear to make it clear that the category has been accepted. How would I enable this functionality.Currently, you have to hit the 'x' button to close.

**Update:**

This is the code which adds new records to my model, and now to my list as well.

```
public void addCategory() {
    categoryRepository.insert(newCategory);
    categories.add(newCategory);
}
```

Comment: use action instead of actionListner like ..`<p:commandButton value="Submit" update=":form:categoryTable"
                                 action="#{categoryController.addCategory}"/>`  ..Also your second question is not clear.please elaborate

Comment: for the submit dialog that doesn't disappear, you can use `oncomplete="widgetVar.hide();"` in your commandButton.

Comment: Thank you, Eric C. The box is now hiding. Pankaj, I've changed actionListener to action and it has no effect; my added categories are still not appearing in the dataTable.

Comment: @Chucky Are you maintaining a list of objects in your managed bean for your datatable? If that is the case you have to add the newly created object in that list.

Comment: Almost there, Eric C! The list is now showing entities, but every time a new one is added, it replaces every entity there. So when adding Geography, then History, Geography turned to History so that there are now 2 history records. I added a categories.add line into my managedBean, and now this happens?

Comment: It is quite unclear what you're trying to do.  You should show the code of your managed bean.  What I can say is that if you have a list to populate your datatable, when creating a new record (Category?), you should add the newly created record to the list by a simple `List.add(record)`.  Updating the table should then show all records in the list.

Comment: That is exactly what I have done (see edit) but for some reason every previous entry gets changed to what the latest one is.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `categories` and `newCategory`.  I would even recommend showing the entire managed bean and the declaration of the datatable. I don't understand what you mean by "every previous entry gets changed to what the latest one is".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33200/discussion-between-eric-c-and-chucky)

Comment: try `newCategory = new Category();` after you add the category to your list

Comment: Thank you danRod. Is this a safe solution? Will a lot of objects not be created after a while?

Comment: It is safe, but if you want to clear your form (xhtml file), you should use `update=@form` or send your input fields.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly do not understand your question. But, come on.
I think you want to display one Dialog.

```
        <p:commandButton id="searchCommandButton" icon="ui-icon-search"
            oncomplete="dialog.show()" value="Mostrar Dialog" update="dataTable"
            actionListener="#{categoryController.addCategory}" />

    <p:confirmDialog id="dialog"
        message="#{wds['dialog.deleteConfirmation.message']}"
        header="#{wds['dialog.deleteConfirmation.header']}"
        widgetVar="dialog" appendToBody="true">
        <p:commandButton id="okCommandButton" onclick="dialog.hide()"
            value="Ok" type="button" />
    </p:confirmDialog>



public void addCategory() {
    categoryRepository.insert(newCategory);
    categories.add(newCategory);
    newCategory = new Category();
}
```